# UITableView when cell scroll to top, the cell will fixed on the top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

In TableView Middle that one "Popular | Latest | Top Sales | Price"
when scroll in tableview, the middle cell will fixed on the top.

So, How to use UITableView Do like this?

Below Sample photo

[Photo Sample First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta4Lq.jpg)

[Photo Sample Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GmDr.jpg)

Comment: you want to use tableView header not cell

Comment: @Lu_ only header can do like this?

Comment: this is not a normal use of cell, you probably could add that view on top of table when original one is hiding or do some other stupid hack

Comment: You can use tableview `headerfooter` for this. @mi1olson

Comment: @iPeter  I go try first :) Thank you.

Comment: @Lu_ Thank you also ^_^

Comment: Check this tut http://zappdesigntemplates.com/collectionview-flow-layout-from-grid-to-list-layout/

Answer (score 0):

You want to add two sections, 
1st header height = 0
2st header height = 44

Answer (score 0):

That was not cell. It was TableView header.

For making custom tableview header use **viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section**.

Below also provided demo code for making custom tableview header.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    //Create Button with title "Popular".
    let b1 = UIButton()
    b1.setTitle("Popular", for: .normal)
    b1.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(95), height: CGFloat(35))
    b1.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)


    //Create Button with title "Latest".
    let b2 = UIButton()
    b2.setTitle("Latest", for: .normal)
    b2.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(105), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(95), height: CGFloat(35))
    b2.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)



    //Create Button with title "Top Sales".
    let b3 = UIButton()
    b3.setTitle("Top sales", for: .normal)
    b3.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(210), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(95), height: CGFloat(35))
    b3.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)



    //Create Button with Title "Price"
    let b4 = UIButton()
    b4.setTitle("Price", for: .normal)
    b4.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(300), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(95), height: CGFloat(35))
    b4.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)


    //Create UIView and Setup UIView
    let view = UIView()
    view.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(365), height: CGFloat(60))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


    //Add Button In UIView
    view.addSubview(b1)
    view.addSubview(b2)
    view.addSubview(b3)
    view.addSubview(b4)


    //Return UiView
    return view
}
```